# jquery remove duplicate li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul id="myid">   
<li>microsoft</li>  
<li>microsoft</li>  
<li>apple</li>  
<li>apple</li>  
</ul>
```

I want to remove duplicates from `li` by using jquery.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are they always next to each other, ordered line this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/PYdsm/)
I find that the script is faster

```
var liText = '', liList = $('#myid li'), listForRemove = [];

$(liList).each(function () {

  var text = $(this).text();

  if (liText.indexOf('|'+ text + '|') == -1)
    liText += '|'+ text + '|';
  else
    listForRemove.push($(this));

})​;

$(listForRemove).each(function () { $(this).remove(); });
```

Comment: Thanks andres descalzo,  How Can we do it with "LIVE" data ??

Comment: could you give an example with what you do, or another question with the problem?

Answer (score 7):

```
uniqueLi = {};

$("#myid li").each(function () {
  var thisVal = $(this).text();

  if ( !(thisVal in uniqueLi) ) {
    uniqueLi[thisVal] = "";
  } else {
    $(this).remove();
  }
})
```

This build an index (an object) of unique values. For your example, `uniqueLi` will look like this afterwards:

```
{
  "microsoft": "", 
  "apple": ""
}
```

So whenever a value is encountered that has been added to the index before, the associated `<li>` gets removed.

Answer (score 6):

You could use

```
var inner = [];
$('li').each( function(index, Element){
    if (jQuery.inArray(this.innerHTML, inner) == -1){
      inner.push(this.innerHTML);
    }
    else {
      $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: `jQuery.inArray()` is kinda inefficient when compared to the `in` operator for objects.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that will do it, a slightly different way:

```
function removeDuplicateItems(id) {
    var ul = $('#' + id);

    $('li', ul).each(function() {
        if($('li:contains("' + $(this).text() + '")', ul).length > 1)
            $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Call with `removeDuplicateItems('myid');`

Comment: This will fail when the item text contains a single quote. ;-)

Comment: I can see why you'd say that, but actually it doesn't—something (either the `contains` selector or the `.text()` function, I can't figure out which from the jQuery source) auto-escapes the quotes. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/kXurk/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “Live”, Dave—if you mean that you are adding more elements to the list client-side and want to de-dupe them as well, just call this function every time you add new elements. Otherwise, please give a bit more explanation (or set up a new question).

Answer (score 1):

I have used @Thariama solution in the past, but I have compatibility problems with IE6 (I still needs to support this dinosaur).

If the item repeats, so remove it from ul. It works with dynamic added li.

```
            var seen = {};
            $("ul#emails_exclusion_list").find("li").each(function(index, html_obj) {
                txt = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

                if(seen[txt]) {
                    $(this).remove();
                } else {
                    seen[txt] = true;
                }
            });
```