# jQuery .append() JSON data in a jQuery Mobile list adding duplicates when page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need help. I can't find my mistake. For some reason I get duplicate li when I append a ul. I created an AJAX search that searches for results upon keyup. The problem is that when I leave the page, for example if I click on profile and come back, if I search the same keyword, I get duplicate results. Which is very weird because I empty() my ul before typing anything in. It might be something very simple but I cannot find it.

Here is my jQuery that appends my ul:

```
    $(document).delegate("#search", "pageshow", function() {
        $("#search input").focus(function() {
            $("ul#search_list").empty();
            $(this).val("");
            localStorage.search = "";
        });
        $("#search input").keyup(function() {
            $("ul#search_list").empty();
            localStorage.search = $("#search input").val();
            var result = "";
            $.ajax({
                url: '/app/users/search/'+localStorage.search,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                success: function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(i,item){
                        var result = '<li><a href="#friend_profile" class="friend_profile" data-search_user_id="'
                        + item.id +
                        '"><img class="round" src="'
                        + item.picture + '" /><h3>'
                        + item.name + 
                        '</h3><p>' + item.location + '</p></a></li>';
                        $("ul#search_list").append(result);
                        $("ul#search_list").listview('refresh');
                    });
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("ul#relationships_list").text('Sorry, you dont seem to have any friends.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is the HTML ul that is being appended:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="search">

            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
                <h1>Search</h1>
                <a href="index.html">Settings</a>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content"> 
                <ul id="search_list" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
                </ul>                 
            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#dash" data-icon="grid">Dash</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#points" data-icon="star">Points</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#claim" data-icon="check">Claim</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#search" data-icon="search" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Search</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#profile" data-icon="home">Profile</a></li>
                    </ul>    
                </div>
            </div><!-- /content -->

        </div><!-- /page -->
```

Here is a screenshot of what appears. In case you want the visual:

[image: iPhone Simulation jQuery Mobile]

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these options worked. But I found a quick fix that removes duplicates in a ul. It is the only thing that has worked so far. Here is a link to the solution:

[jquery remove duplicate li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838845/jquery-remove-duplicate-li)

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue once where I cleared the results on page hide.  I'm not sure what version of JQueryMobile you're using, but I had this issue in 1.0.  The ajax event doesn't seem to destroy the page on pagehide, so I had to remove the elements on pagehide.  I don't know if this helps.