# Why is jquery/javascript creating duplicate list items in a jquery mobile listview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to build a JQuery Mobile listview (based on the [getting started guide](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/about/getting-started.html)).  The list items are populated by json data.

It is basically working. The list is being created and and styled properly. But the list includes duplicates. There are only 2 json objects, but the list includes four items. The last two are repeats of the first two.

I have double checked the json data and output the variables to the console.  Both only contain the two objects, without duplicates.

Why is this jquery/javascript creating duplicate list items in the listview?  How can I prevent the duplicates?

My problem may be similar to the problem described at [jQuery .append() JSON data in a jQuery Mobile list adding duplicates when page is refreshed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399510/jquery-append-json-data-in-a-jquery-mobile-list-adding-duplicates-when-page-i).  But the only solutions offered don't prevent the duplicates, they only explain how to filter out the duplicates.  That seems like an inefficient kludge.

Here my javascript ([live version] (http://dev.mycourtdates.com/jq.html))::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>J 2.1</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id = "myList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
            <script>
            $.getJSON("http://dev.mycourtdates.com/jsonData.txt?",
                {
                    id: "73125"
                },
                function(data) {
                    var items = [];

                    $.each(data, function(i,ct_setting){
                        items.push('<li><a href="#">' + ct_setting.caseNumber + '</a></li');
                    });
                    console.log(items);
                    $('#myList').append(items).listview('refresh');
                });
            </script>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my json data ([live version] (http://dev.mycourtdates.com/jsonData.txt)):

```
[
   {
      "active":"1",
      "caseNumber":"B 1102907-C",
      "timeDate":"2012-07-31 09:00:00",
      "setting":"JURY TRIAL",
      "location":"H.C. COURT HOUSE ROOM 320",
      "plaintiffs":"STATE OF OHIO",
      "defendants":"EDWARD L HOGAN",
      "attorneyId":"PP68519"
   },
   {
      "active":"",
      "caseNumber":"B 1200563",
      "timeDate":"2012-08-06 09:00:00",
      "setting":"JURY TRIAL",
      "location":"H.C. COURT HOUSE ROOM 320",
      "plaintiffs":"STATE OF OHIO",
      "defendants":"RONALD SILER ",
      "attorneyId":"PP68519"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<script>` tag is in an invalid location.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWUXf/) is working:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul id = "myList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

The following Javascript should be placed in a `<script>` tag in your header.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://dev.mycourtdates.com/jsonData.txt?",
            {
                id: "73125"
            },
            function(data) {
                var items = [];

                $.each(data, function(i,ct_setting){
                    items.push('<li><a href="#">' + ct_setting.caseNumber + '</a></li');
                });
                console.log(items);
                $('#myList').append(items).listview('refresh');
            });
});
```

Note I had to change the JSON source in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TWUXf/) because of Access Control Header restrictions on your source above.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That did the trick.  Was                 $('#myList').append(items).listview('refresh') being called twice--once when the document loaded and then again when the script in the body tag was executed?