# Delete repeated li in a ul list

Tags: jquery, html

I have a ul list in where I dynamically display several li's from a file. Some of them appear to have the same tag, so I want to remove them an leave only one of them:

I have this:

```
    <ul id="dealers-ul" data-next="#branches-ul">
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344410" value="Barcelona Premium"><label for=" 344410 "> Barcelona Premium</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343594" value="Barcelona Premium"><label for=" 343594 "> Barcelona Premium</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343584" value="Barcelona Premium"><label for=" 343584 "> Barcelona Premium</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344444" value="Barcelona Premium"><label for=" 344444 "> Barcelona Premium</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343882" value="Ibericar Cadí"><label for=" 343882 "> Ibericar Cadí</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343640" value="Ibericar Cadí"><label for=" 343640 "> Ibericar Cadí</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343856" value="Motor Munich"><label for=" 343856 "> Motor Munich</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343831" value="Motor Munich"><label for=" 343831 "> Motor Munich</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344363" value="Motor Munich"><label for=" 344363 "> Motor Munich</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343902" value="Motor Munich"><label for=" 343902 "> Motor Munich</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344450" value="Nürburgring"><label for=" 344450 "> Nürburgring</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344421" value="Pruna Motor"><label for=" 344421 "> Pruna Motor</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343628" value="Pruna Motor"><label for=" 343628 "> Pruna Motor</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343647" value="Sitjas"><label for=" 343647 "> Sitjas</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343892" value="Tallcar"><label for=" 343892 "> Tallcar</label></li>
</ul>
```

And I only want 1 of Barcelona Premium, one of Ibericar Cadí, one of Motor Munich, one of Pruna...

Comment: how do you output the content from the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery remove duplicate li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838845/jquery-remove-duplicate-li)

Comment: While JavaScript, or any of its libraries, can do this it would be better to solve the problem on the server side to prevent the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var listForRemove = [];
var listOfUniqe = [];
$('#dealers-ul li').each(function () {

  var text = $(this).text().trim();

  if (listOfUniqe.indexOf(text) === -1)
    listOfUniqe.push(text);
  else
    listForRemove.push($(this));
});

$(listForRemove).each(function () { $(this).remove(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="dealers-ul" data-next="#branches-ul">
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344410" value="Barcelona Premium"><label for=" 344410 "> Barcelona Premium</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343594" value="Barcelona Premium"><label for=" 343594 "> Barcelona Premium</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343584" value="Barcelona Premium"><label for=" 343584 "> Barcelona Premium</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344444" value="Barcelona Premium"><label for=" 344444 "> Barcelona Premium</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343882" value="Ibericar Cadí"><label for=" 343882 "> Ibericar Cadí</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343640" value="Ibericar Cadí"><label for=" 343640 "> Ibericar Cadí</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343856" value="Motor Munich"><label for=" 343856 "> Motor Munich</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343831" value="Motor Munich"><label for=" 343831 "> Motor Munich</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344363" value="Motor Munich"><label for=" 344363 "> Motor Munich</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343902" value="Motor Munich"><label for=" 343902 "> Motor Munich</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344450" value="Nürburgring"><label for=" 344450 "> Nürburgring</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344421" value="Pruna Motor"><label for=" 344421 "> Pruna Motor</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343628" value="Pruna Motor"><label for=" 343628 "> Pruna Motor</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343647" value="Sitjas"><label for=" 343647 "> Sitjas</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343892" value="Tallcar"><label for=" 343892 "> Tallcar</label></li>
</ul>
```

This should do the job :)

Answer (score 2):

hope this is helpful for you

```js
  uniqueLi = {};

$("#dealers-ul li").each(function () {
  var thisVal = $(this).text();

  if ( !(thisVal in uniqueLi) ) {
    uniqueLi[thisVal] = "";
  } else {
    $(this).remove();
  }
})
console.log(uniqueLi);
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="dealers-ul" data-next="#branches-ul">
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344410" value="Barcelona Premium"><label for=" 344410 "> Barcelona Premium</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343594" value="Barcelona Premium"><label for=" 343594 "> Barcelona Premium</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343584" value="Barcelona Premium"><label for=" 343584 "> Barcelona Premium</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344444" value="Barcelona Premium"><label for=" 344444 "> Barcelona Premium</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343882" value="Ibericar Cadí"><label for=" 343882 "> Ibericar Cadí</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343640" value="Ibericar Cadí"><label for=" 343640 "> Ibericar Cadí</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343856" value="Motor Munich"><label for=" 343856 "> Motor Munich</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343831" value="Motor Munich"><label for=" 343831 "> Motor Munich</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344363" value="Motor Munich"><label for=" 344363 "> Motor Munich</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343902" value="Motor Munich"><label for=" 343902 "> Motor Munich</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344450" value="Nürburgring"><label for=" 344450 "> Nürburgring</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="344421" value="Pruna Motor"><label for=" 344421 "> Pruna Motor</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343628" value="Pruna Motor"><label for=" 343628 "> Pruna Motor</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343647" value="Sitjas"><label for=" 343647 "> Sitjas</label></li>
<li class="select-option"><input type="radio" name="choice" id="343892" value="Tallcar"><label for=" 343892 "> Tallcar</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would perhaps be better to not add the repeated items to begin with. This code will remove the repeated items.

```js
var liText = '',
  liList = $('#dealers-ul li'),
  listForRemove = [];

$(liList).each(function() {

  var text = $(this).text();

  if (liText.indexOf('|' + text + '|') == -1)
    liText += '|' + text + '|';
  else
    listForRemove.push($(this));

});

$(listForRemove).each(function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<ul id="dealers-ul" data-next="#branches-ul">
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="344410" value="Barcelona Premium">
    <label for=" 344410 "> Barcelona Premium</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="343594" value="Barcelona Premium">
    <label for=" 343594 "> Barcelona Premium</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="343584" value="Barcelona Premium">
    <label for=" 343584 "> Barcelona Premium</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="344444" value="Barcelona Premium">
    <label for=" 344444 "> Barcelona Premium</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="343882" value="Ibericar Cadí">
    <label for=" 343882 "> Ibericar Cadí</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="343640" value="Ibericar Cadí">
    <label for=" 343640 "> Ibericar Cadí</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="343856" value="Motor Munich">
    <label for=" 343856 "> Motor Munich</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="343831" value="Motor Munich">
    <label for=" 343831 "> Motor Munich</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="344363" value="Motor Munich">
    <label for=" 344363 "> Motor Munich</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="343902" value="Motor Munich">
    <label for=" 343902 "> Motor Munich</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="344450" value="Nürburgring">
    <label for=" 344450 "> Nürburgring</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="344421" value="Pruna Motor">
    <label for=" 344421 "> Pruna Motor</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="343628" value="Pruna Motor">
    <label for=" 343628 "> Pruna Motor</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="343647" value="Sitjas">
    <label for=" 343647 "> Sitjas</label>
  </li>
  <li class="select-option">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="343892" value="Tallcar">
    <label for=" 343892 "> Tallcar</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Source: [jquery remove duplicate li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838845/jquery-remove-duplicate-li)